# what do I do with compiled interface output?

Tags: tokens, interfaces

I created a token sale smart contract. And it has an interface that resolves to a token contract address.

Now the output folder has the compiled token sale smart json file and the interface json file.....

When I deploy the token sale smart contract, what do I do with the interface output?

Comment: an interface that resolves to an address? never heard of this.

Comment: @Nulik？token public tokenReward; then in constructor: tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);

Comment: in that case you should read more documentation first. check about the ABI and how to call contract methods